# bootstrap Dual Listbox knockout binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, bootstrap-duallistbox

I am using [bootstrap dual listbox pluging](https://github.com/istvan-ujjmeszaros/bootstrap-duallistbox) in my ASP.NET MVC project. 
I am also using Knockout in the project. I am trying to create `bindingHandler` for the this plugin to make it working smoothly with knockout.

here is what I tried

**Binding Handler**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dualList = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).bootstrapDualListbox({
            selectorMinimalHeight: 160
        });

        $(element).on('change', function () {
            $(element).bootstrapDualListbox('refresh', true);
        });

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).bootstrapDualListbox('destroy');
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).bootstrapDualListbox('refresh', true);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="foreach:{data: EditedElement().Operations, as : 'op'} , dualList: EditedElement().Operations" multiple>
    <option data-bind="value: op.OperationID(), text: op.Name(), selected: op.IsSelected()"></option>
</select>
```

**View Model**

```
function SelectOperationVM(operationId, isSelected, name) {
    var self = this;

    self.OperationID = ko.observable(operationId);
    self.IsSelected = ko.observable(isSelected);
    self.Name = ko.observable(name);

    self.copy = function () {
        return new SelectOperationVM(self.OperationID(), self.IsSelected(), self.Name());
    }
}
```

**My problem is** that I can not make sync between the viewModel `observableArray`, and the plugin.
In other words, I want the changes in the plugin (the user removed some options or added some options) to be reflected on the view model property, and vice verse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to sync, you need to pass multiple observables to custom binding

so your html should be like

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="foreach: { data: Operations, as: 'op'}, dualList: { options: Operations, selected: Selected }" multiple>
    <option data-bind="value: op.OperationID(), text: op.Name(), selected: op.IsSelected()"></option>
</select>
```

and custom binding be like

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dualList = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var data = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    $(element).bootstrapDualListbox({
      selectorMinimalHeight: 160
    });

    $(element).on('change', function() {
      // save selected to an observable  
      data.selected($(element).val());;
    });

    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
      $(element).bootstrapDualListbox('destroy');
    });
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    // to view if there is an update (without this "update" will not fire)
    var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()).options();
    $(element).bootstrapDualListbox('refresh', true);
  }
}
```

also i have created a dirty working [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jb5o7vum/)

Comment: seems it is helpful, it will check that and accept the answer according to that check. Thanks any way for your time

Comment: the `selected` observable is `undefined` when I querying it outside the `binding Handler` do you have any idea of the possible cause of that.

Comment: Thank you very much, This solved the problem, but I had to say that I made 2 modifications on your code *this could be helpful for others readying your answer* **First Modification** was changing the `selected` from `observable` to `observableArray` **Second Modification** I needed to move the statement `var data = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());` to inside the `change` event. This was very important to be able to read the `selected` property from outside the `binding Handler`, because as I said before, I was receiving null when trying to read this property from the model itself.